# Polynomial with "quarter square" coefficients

Tags: polynomials

I have encountered some polynomials in my work that have the following form:

- $n=2$: $1$
- $n=3$: $\phi^2 + 2\phi + 1$
- $n=4$: $\phi^4 + 2\phi^3 + 4\phi^2 + 2\phi + 1$
- $n=5$: $\phi^6 + 2\phi^5 + 4\phi^4 + 6\phi^3 + 4\phi^2 + 2\phi + 1$
- $n=6$: $\phi^8 + 2\phi^7 + 4\phi^6 + 6\phi^5 + 9\phi^4 + 6\phi^3 +
     4\phi^2 + 2\phi + 1$
- $n=7$: $\phi^{10} + 2\phi^9 + 4\phi^8 + 6\phi^7 + 9\phi^6 + 12\phi^5
     + 9\phi^4 + 6\phi^3 + 4\phi^2 + 2\phi + 1$
- $n=8$: $\phi^{12} + 2\phi^{11} + 4\phi^{10} + 6\phi^9 + 9\phi^8 +
     12\phi^7 + 16\phi^6 + 12\phi^5 + 9\phi^4 + 6\phi^3 + 4\phi^2 + 2\phi
     + 1$
- $n=9$: $\phi^{14} + 2\phi^{13} + 4\phi^{12} + 6\phi^{11} + 9\phi^{10}
     + 12\phi^9 + 16\phi^8 + 20\phi^7 + 16\phi^6 + 12\phi^5 + 9\phi^4 + 6\phi^3 + 4\phi^2 + 2\phi + 1$

I am trying to figure out if there is a closed-form expression for the polynomial.

The coefficients follow the ["quarter squares"](https://oeis.org/A002620) sequence, which looks like this:

| n | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| floor($\frac{n^2}{4}$) | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 9 | 12 | 16 | 20 | 25 | 30 | 36 | 42 | 49 | 56 | 64 | 72 |

To avoid using the floor/ceiling function, the sequence can be defined also as ["the square numbers and pronic numbers interleaved"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lozani%C4%87%27s_triangle), with [pronic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronic_number) defined as "the product of two consecutive integers". Or as a piecewise function:

- $ q(n) = \frac{n^2}{4}$ if n is even
- $ q(n) = \frac{n-1}{2} \cdot \frac{n+1}{2}$ if n is odd

Using sums and using $q(n)$ to denote the $n$-th element of the sequence above, we get the following form:

$q(n) \cdot \phi^{n - 2} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} \left(q(n-i) \cdot \left(\phi^{n - 2 + i} + \phi^{n - 2 - i}\right) \right)$

Does anyone have an idea of how to simplify these polynomials?

Comment: No idea whether it helps but a non-negative integer $k$ is pronic if and only if $4k+1$ is a perfect square ($1$ included).